# Google Spreadsheet Creating a parameterised / dynamic menu

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, submenu

I am trying to make a menu interface for a Google Docs Spreadsheet.  The goal is to have the ability to click the menu and select a mode (one of a mutually exclusive list) which will then trigger the scripts to adapt the data accordingly.

I am able to make the functions, but the choice of modes is dynamic (selecting a user, the list of users may change, but is a small list).  I can make the menu update the list of menu entries, but as each can only call a function I can find no easy way to get the information of "which mode" back into the script.

Ideally I would like to have a submenu with ~5-10 entries which when clicked will all call the same function but with the menu text or an index as the parameter.  Is there any way to do this?

E.g menu with items Choice A, Choice B, Choice C
When clicked they trigger a function activateChosenMode(choice), so that if I later add a Choice D into my list of available choices this works too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I couldn't find an elegant way of doing it, there doesn't seem to be a way to set any form of callback from a menu so in the end I brute forced it with 120 functions (and a little autogeneration).  It's a form of solution.